# A little help with odd syntax from Twilio gist

Tags: null-pointer

I've been testing Twilios's Salesforce integration and after all the hassle that they do not mention in their blog (deploy unmanaged package to sandbox first, add API key to config page that is deeply buried, add their API URL to permissions) I finally made it somewhat work.

However, it will throw exception if I do not have a contact with the caller number in Salesforce. Here's the source code:

```
// Look up contact from incoming caller id
String fromNumber = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('From');
List<Contact> callers = (fromNumber == null) 
    ? null 
    : [SELECT Name, OwnerId 
       FROM Contact 
       WHERE Phone = :fromNumber OR MobilePhone = :fromNumber];
Contact caller = (callers != null && callers.size() == 1) 
    ? callers[0]
    : null;
callerName = caller.Name;

// Look up rep from contact
List<User> reps = (caller == null) 
    ? null 
    : [SELECT Name, Phone 
       FROM User 
       WHERE Id = :caller.OwnerId];

// If we don't have a unique rep, connect with switchboard
rep = (reps != null && reps.size() == 1) 
    ? reps[0] 
    : [SELECT Name, Phone 
       FROM User 
       WHERE LastName = 'Swichboard'];
```

I get error:

```
14:09:48.427 (427654749)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[22]|Aggregations:0|select Name, OwnerId from Contact where (Phone = :tmpVar1 or MobilePhone = :tmpVar2)
14:09:48.432 (432400267)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[22]|Rows:0
14:09:48.432 (432531259)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[27]|LIST<Contact>.size()
14:09:48.432 (432555617)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[27]|LIST<Contact>.size()
14:09:48.432 (432587879)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[30]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

So it seems that it breaks trying to assign caller.Name?

I've never seen such syntax, so perhaps someone could assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is using an [inline form of if/else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) which when used appropriately makes for clearer code.

But the above isn't a coding style to emulate. A quick fix would be to add the same sort of null guard used in the rest of the code:

```
callerName = (caller == null)
    ? null
    : caller.Name;
```

(Code full of null checks like the above is hard to understand and easy to break. Generally it is better to return empty lists rather than null values so code that loops over the lists just works whether there are list entries or not. And also to break the pieces of work out into separate methods whose names explain what is being done rather than to add comments to a long line of code. Then the top level method reads pretty much like the specification of what is being done.)

Comment: Ternary operators are perfectly acceptable though. I use them to reduce code coverage surface area and condense otherwise verbose branches of logic into a single statement. However, the developer here made some poor assumptions and it resulted in missing that NPE. +1 for mentioning that you should avoid null references if at all possible, because it is definitely brittle.

Comment: Thanks. I've used `? fromNumber` instead, but that's just my use case.